# Clean user input using javascript before showing updated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, xss

On one of the pages (a  user's profile) the user can edit their information. The updated info( name, tagline etc) is then saved used AJAX. These are the steps I follow:

a) The user inputs the data and clicks on save.

b) I send the (unverified) data to the server using ajax

c) The data is cleaned on the server side for XSS and saved using Active Record to avoid SQL injections.

d) On the client side if the AJAX request was successful the user's new data (the unverified one on client side) replaces the older one.

Now say it is malicious user and they insert some JS code, the JS code will work once after the update because the data is not being checked on the client side. However if the user refreshes the screen the clean verified data takes its place and the JS will not run. Are there any potential security loopholes to this approach?

Comment: No, that's the common approach. Never trust a browser (or any other data coming from the web). As long as you clean and validate properly on the server they can send you whatever you want and your code ignores it. They refresh and what they see is the data as it was before they sent you trash. You can do additional javascript validation, but that's a usability thing to show the user typos or missing data earlier, never trust it, verify on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not intended to include HTML, use $.text (or .innerText) and $.attr (or .setAttribute) to update the view. Alternatively, you ajax call can return safe HTML snippets.